# Firebase - Switching to WebSocket protocol - handshake not working

Tags: firebase, rest, firebase-realtime-database, websocket, esp8266

I'm using ESP-01/ESP8266 Wifi module to make SSL connection to my google firebase project.
I'm already able to write/read to/from the database using HTTP protocol and REST API, and my next goal is to switch the protocol to WebSocket, in order the server and client (my board) can speak this protocol after the initial handshake. Currently I'm not even making the handshking to work, and this is the point I'm currently stuck.

*What I tried so far:*

(1) First, I open TCP socket with SSL, connect to ***wss://eletronica-ab6b1.firebaseio.com***, port ***443***. The SSL steps are being done by the wifi module, SSL/TLS is one of its features.

(2) After connection is up, I send the following HTTP packet to the server, actually is only a HTTP header, without data. Packet:

`GET /January HTTP/1.1
Host: eletronica-ab6b1.firebaseio.com
Upgrade: Websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Sec-WebSocket-Key: dGhlIHNhbXBsZSBub25jZQ==`

This is the response of the server:

[image]

Why I used "January"? Check, this is my database:

[image]

What do I need to change in order to work? I mean in terms of content of the headers and also the connection to the domain.

Regards.

**EDIT:**
My final goal is: the board stablish a constant TCP connection to firebase server. When a value of the database be changed, the board will be notified by the server through the protocol, so there will be no need of the board to stay polling the server (each X seconds) to know if the value was changed. Am I on the right way to reach this? Using WebSocket protocol?

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it but you could find a way to achieve something similar to websockets using gRpc https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rpc/

Comment: I don't know about RPC protocol, I will read about soon. My final goal is: the board stablish a constant TCP connection to firebase server. When a value of the database be changed, the board will be notified by the server through the protocol, so there will be no need of the board to stay polling the server (each X seconds) to know if the value was changed.